# Python split() at string ""

Tags: python, split

Is it possible to split() string at " "? I have tried

```
x=str(input("Enter string to split: ")) #Input: one "two three"
xsplit=str.split()
print(xsplit[1])
```

but it returns "two" but I want it to show "two three".
How to do it?

Comment: Hmm.. I think so. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Curiously, are you trying to parse a TSV file ?

Comment: Not quite. I am just messing around with discord.py

Comment: Well, I tried it in my python code, it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use module [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to split it. `shlex.split('one "two three" "four five"')` gives `['one', 'two three', 'four five']`. And if you want to split only on first space then `text.split(' ', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This will let you split on the space as well as gather everything after the split.

```
x=str(input("Enter string to split: ")) #Input: one "two three"
xsplit = x.split(' ')[1:]
xjoin = ' '.join(xsplit)
print(xjoin)
```

Once you have split into a list you can rejoin the list into a single string with .join(xsplit)

Comment: I think the OP was trying to respect the quotes around the second and third arguments, not just grab all elements after the first

Comment: Right, but this would still bring back the quotes right, or am I still missing something haha?